# Balls and Buckets.

Tags: probability, reference-request, random-variables, concentration-of-measure

**Problem setting:** There are $R$ red balls and $B$ blue balls along with $R$ red buckets and $B$ blue buckets. Consider the case when $R \ll B$

**Event:** $R+B$ balls are arranged in $R+B$ buckets such that each bucket contains one ball, and each of the $(R+B)!$ combinations occur with equal probability.

**Quantity of interest:** Let $X$ be a random variable which denotes the number of *red* balls in *red* buckets. How do we bound the following?
$$\mathbb{P}\big( X - \mathbb{E}[X] > t \big)$$

**Salient points**

1. Using combinatorics it is easy to show that $$\mathbb{P}\big(X=x\big)= \binom{k}{x}\binom{n-k}{k-x}\Big/\binom{n}{k}$$
2. If we naively (and *wrongly*) assume that each red ball falling in a red bucket is an independent event, we have $X\sim Binom(\frac{R}{R+B},R)$ and using Chernoff's bound gives us
   $$\mathbb{P}\big( X - \mathbb{E}[X] > t \big)\leq \exp-\bigg\{\frac{t^2}{2\mathbb{E}[X]+t}\bigg\}.$$ 
   **However**, it turns out that we can derive the above result using [Stein's method of exchangeable pairs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604352.pdf).

**My question:** For $R\ll B$, I suspect the above concentration can be strengthened to

$$\mathbb{P}\big( X - \mathbb{E}[X] > t \big)\leq \exp-\bigg\{\frac{t^2}{2\mathbb{E}[X]}\bigg\}.$$
Why do I think so?

1. Wrongly assuming $X\sim Pois(\mathbb{E}[X])$ or $X\sim \mathcal{N}\big(\mathbb{E}[X],Var(X)\big)$ will give us the above result.
2. Simulations also seem to support my claim.

Comment: Using martingales gives us $\mathbb{P}\big(X-\mathbb{E}[X]\big) \leq \exp-\Big\{\frac{t^2}{2R}\Big\}$.